# Data Project using SSDT, how to reference another database without it populating in same project folder in SS Obj Explorer

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, database-project, dacpac

I have a Database Project in Visual Studio called AMC.

In AMC I have a view, which references an object in another Database (on same instance) called AMC2 that was raising errors in the project; the error was it didn't recognize the AMC2 reference.

So I got the dacpac from AMC2 and added it as a reference. Now my view script doesn't throw errors in the projects as it has a known reference, but in my SQL Server Object Explorer (in Visual Studio), I'm seeing stored procedures and tables etc from the other AMC2 being combined with AMC.

How can I reference AMC2 in my AMC database project without that mixing of db objects happening in the SQL Server Object Explorer under my AMC Project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an option in VS SQL Object Explorer to not show external objects. Click the Filter button at the top and turn off "Show External Objects" to stop seeing the objects not actually in your DB.
[image]

Comment: I found it, except for me it was under "Show results" where you have that funnel shown in the picture. Perhaps b\c I have an older version of VS (2012). Thanks!

Comment: Yeah - didn't think to pull up a couple of screenshots. I know that MS has been tweaking that UX a little along the way. I've been hit by that several times and it usually takes me a couple of seconds or so to remember that I need to set that filter.